# jquery refresh div on activity

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I have made simply chat box application using (Ajax/jQuery, MySQL, PHP). Here is my application: http://userhelio.byethost13.com/Chatvv/index.php . As you can ses (when you highlight the text of message) div tag is refreshed  every second.I want to refresh the div tag only when I click on "send message" button (submit button). In other words, when there is an activity on the page.

Thanks

Comment: Handle your logic in the button click event instead of div click

Comment: Can you show your script which does that ??

Comment: What do you mean by refresh div tag? In jQuery, you can attach a handler form submit and do the refresh on div.

Comment: Are you sure it's your code? It seems obfuscated to me, which makes me doubt its credibility. Your "javascript1.js" file has a setInterval() statement which executes every second, which causes it to refresh all the time...

Comment: The script which refreshing whole div tag for displaying messages?

Comment: Yes it's my code. I use this: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx for secure reasons :)

Comment: setInterval(function() {
                $('#result').load('data.php');
            }, 500);

Comment: You can see now my web logic in javascript1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setInterval() statement in your code is the likely culprit that causes it to be refreshed every second:

```
setInterval(function() { $('#result').load('data.php'); }, 500);
```

Remove that from your one script file and it should stop refreshing all the time. Rather replace it with a click-handler for your button that executes the code-block in the function of the interval.

You can set it as follows (assuming your button has an ID of "buttonID"):

```
$('#buttonID').click(function () { $('#result').load('data.php'); });
```

To do an initial load on the page, add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('#result').load('data.php'); });
```

Comment: What to you think to put this $('#result').load('data.php'); code in my javascipt2 (pastesite.com/45341) ???

Comment: I have updated my code. But on the beginning there is noting to see. You have to submit your first message to view other messages.

Comment: Maybe i have to put this code $('#result').load('data.php');  before submit (between ready and submit): I quess this is a good idea ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I have to always refresh the page to seeing the incoming messages

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but you can add an event on the DOM ready to do the initial load. Try adding the following the code in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you have right! The idea for the initial load is good. But after i have to refresh the page always if i want to see my incoming messages (from another user). We can tasted if you will ?

Comment: In the original question you said you only want to refresh when you click the button? If I understand you correctly now, you want to refresh each chat participant's window when someone sends a message. Using standard HTML and JavaScript you won't be able to do that - each user's window will have to poll the server for new messages. You can't "push" messages to participants in a browser, because the request-response nature of HTTP won't allow for that.

Comment: Yes, like comment feature in Facebook. We don't have to press F5 (refresh the page) to view incoming comments in Facebook. Comments are dynamically displayed but not as in my case (I don't think Facebook use this script: setInterval(function() { $('#result').load('data.php'); }, 500);   I tested youe idea so I opened Mozilla and Chrome. And when I input message in Mozilla I can see this message in Mozilla but not in Chrome. Yes I want to refresh each chat participant's window when someone sends a message (I think Facebook use this)

Comment: I actually want to built something like Facebook comment feature, as I said we don't have to refresh the page when user send the message.

Comment: AFAIK, Facebook also uses a setInterval to poll for new messages. Web-browser technology isn't sophisticated enough yet to facilitate push messages through sockets or something similar. For now you'll have to stick with the setInterval option to do auto-refreshes...

Comment: Yes, I understand.  But how can you explain following: In my web application (http://userhelio.byethost13.com/Chatvv/index.php) you **can't highlight** the text of messages (because it is refreshed every second), And when you go to Facebook you **can highlight** the text of comments ??? Because of this there is an another question: Maybe they (Facebook) refresh only the last row in database (not whole div (content of message)) !?

Comment: That's exactly what they do. Instead of replacing the contents of the div after every refresh, rather append any new messages to the div. So you should keep track of any unread messages for the specific user and only retrieve those.

Comment: Yes ,I think  I have implemented it. I can you send the code if you want or should I paste it here?

Comment: You can draw up a jsFiddle to illustrate what you've done, then I can amend it if necessary and help you that way. Would you be able to do that?

Comment: It really wouldn't be necessary, you only need to make changes to your database to store a timestamp or GUID for the last message the user received and then only return messages received AFTER that update. You then only append the messages to the DIV instead of replacing the DIV's contents entirely.

Comment: Exactly, Tha'ts what I've done. Here is the link you can see my last implementation: http://userhelio.byethost13.com/Chatvv/index.php. Write something that I know you were there.

Comment: Seems to work fine now? I left a comment... You know, you might consider marking this as the answer seeing as I've pointed you in the right direction. :)

Comment: I have had  that idea before you have told me. I just want to know other opinions. I think it's the only way to get good programmer. I'm proud of myself because I've built my own chat app even  if I didn't use any Comet or something like. However, thank you for all. P.S. Maybe you are a little angry because there is Steven Jobs pic. not Bill Gates because you are Microsoft employer :)

Comment: I'm most certainly not a Microsoft employee. I just prefer working with Microsoft tech. :) Old Jobs was a good man and so is Bill.